# Retrieve memory usage by process in FreeBSD system

Tags: c++, freebsd

In Linux we can retrieve memory usage by process using `/proc/[id]/stat`, `/proc/[id]/status`.

But in FreeBSD we don't have file `stat`, and in file `/proc/[id]/status` we don't have a field that tell us how much memory is used by process with specific id.

So, how I can retrieve this value? I want retrieve this value in my c++ program for monitoring.

Comment: I would suggest asking on of the dedicated mailing lists http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html Most FreeBSD developers are subscribed and in general their responses are quick and helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for procstat(1) utility. For instance, to retrieve resource usage you can use command:

```
procstat -r $PID
```

To use it for own program, there is libprocstat(3) library. The "procstat -r" uses function "procstat_getprocs" to retrieve information about resource usage, so you can use following source code is example: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_rusage.c

Answer (score 0):

There's also the getrusage(2) system call.